# Drop operations when new value is emitted

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

Is there a way to drop all operations on a flow that is being collected when a new value is emitted, so that the new value gets to be processed while the old one is dropped and not processed further down the flow once the new value is emitted?

Comment: A flow is a stream of values. If you care about a single value only, why use flow to begin with?

Comment: @huytc I care about THE most recent value. If a new value has been emitted before the old one was fully processed I want to drop that old value alltogether and start processing the newly emitted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for Flow.collectLatest

[kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect-latest](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/collect-latest.html)

Comment: Well I was aware of collectLast but it:
    1. works only on the very last flow it's executed on not on the original one that operations were executed on
    2. requires modification of flow collection in order to work properly

I'll accept your answer as correct as I was about to answer the same, since I did not find better solution.